# Combining averages for Monte Carlo

Tags: probability

To determine the combined mean for use in a Monte Carlo Simulation, would it be appropriate to use the simple average or a weighted average???

Answer (score 1):

Use a weighted average please.  For example, if the mean of the first sample is $m_1$ with a sample size of  $n_1$, and the mean of the second sample is $m_2$ with a sample size of $n_2$, then the overall mean is:
$$
m = \dfrac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}m_1 + \dfrac{n_2}{n_1+n_2}m_2.
$$
So the weights depend upon the sample sizes.

Comment: The sample size of the returns is the same its the principle amount of the investments that's different!

Comment: I’m confused.  What problem are you trying to solve?  If it’s a finance problem and the returns are in percents, then the amount invested has nothing to do with percent returns of the overall portfolio.